# Targeting one of multiple Classes / only part of the Class string - className vs classList

Tags: javascript, toggle, getelementsbytagname, classname, getelementsbyclassname

So I'm trying to put together a Javascript toggle for my photography portfolio site. My goal is to be able to click a button labeled Show Only Sunsets and hide every image without a "Sunsets" Class. The code I've come up with below ALMOST works, but there's a major flaw:

This code only preserves the visibility of images such as "1.jpg" below whose Class is exactly/only "Sunsets" (or "NSFW," or whatever). But often I'll need to give images more than one class, for example to differentiate verticals, or images that fall into multiple categories. So I need the code to preserve the visibility of any image such as "2.jpg" below which has "Sunsets" (or whatever) anywhere in its Class.

**JS:**

```
<script>
        function filterOn(imageClass) {
            var image = document.getElementsByTagName('figure');
            for (i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                if (image[i].className != imageClass) {
                    image[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(imageClass + '-off').innerHTML = 'Undo Filter';
            document.getElementById(imageClass + '-off').setAttribute('onClick', "filterOff('" + imageClass + "')");
            document.getElementById(imageClass + '-off').id = imageClass + '-on';
        }
        function filterOff(imageClass) {
            var image = document.getElementsByTagName('figure');
            for (i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                if (image[i].className != imageClass) {
                    image[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(imageClass + '-on').innerHTML = 'Show Only ' + imageClass;
            document.getElementById(imageClass + '-on').setAttribute('onClick', "filterOn('" + imageClass + "')");
            document.getElementById(imageClass + '-on').id = imageClass + '-off';
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <ul>
        <li id="Sunsets-off" onClick="filterOn('Sunsets')">Show Only Sunsets</li>
        <li id="NSFW-off" onClick="filterOn('NSFW')">Show Only NSFW</li>
    </ul>
    <img class="Sunsets" src="1.jpg">
    <img class="vertical Sunsets" src="2.jpg">
    <img class="NSFW vertical" src="3.jpg">
    <img class="Architectural" src="4.jpg">
    <img class="Sunsets Landscapes" src="5.jpg">
    <img class="Abstract" src="6.jpg">
    <img class="NSFW LondonAndrews" src="7.jpg">
```

Comment: Nitpick: do not set events with setAttribute. That is what addEventListener is for.

Comment: You miss-typed 'imageclass' in the last line of filterOff() and why your code's finding 'figure' tag? I think it should be 'img'.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks! I was only familiar with "getElementById.innerHTML" syntax used for static attribute, so when I discovered that doesn't work for the onClick attribute, I was basically guessing/Googling. Can you give me the exact syntax to use?

Comment: @margincall Thank you! That fixed problem #2!

Comment: addEventListener : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That test:

```
if (image[i].className != imageClass) {
```

will indeed do a check against the whole class string.
There's the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API for doing what you want, replacing your test with:

```
if (!image[i].classList.contains(imageClass)) {
```

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify it by adding a class name to all images so you can easily target all the images, then use a toggled class to hide the images you don't want to see. this also gives you the ability to use css3 animations to fade the images you don't want to see.

```js
function filterOn( clazz ){
  // get all the images using the additional img class
  var images = slice(document.getElementsByClassName('img'));
  // hide all the images
  var ret = images.map(function( image ){
    image.classList.add('hide');
    return image;
  })
  // reduce the images to only contain those you want to show
  .filter(function( image ){
    return image.classList.contains( clazz );
  })
  // show the image by removing the hide class
  .forEach(function( image ){
    image.classList.remove('hide');
  });
}

// show all images
function showAll(){
  var images = slice(document.getElementsByClassName('img'));
  images.forEach(function( image ){
    image.classList.remove('hide');
  });
}
// helper function to get an array from an array like object
function slice( arrayLike ){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call( arrayLike );
}
```

```css
.img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: .8em;
  border: .3em solid #aaa;
}

.hide {
   display: none;
}

.filters {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.Sunsets {
  border: .3em solid orange;
}

.NSFW {
  border: .3em solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<nav class="filters">
  <button id="Sunsets-off" onClick="filterOn('Sunsets')">Show Only Sunsets</button>
  <button id="NSFW-off" onClick="filterOn('NSFW')">Show Only NSFW</button>
  <button id="show-all" onClick="showAll()">Show All</button>
</nav>
<!-- I added an img class to the images for ease of use later -->
<section class="images">
  <img class="img Sunsets" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
  <img class="img vertical Sunsets" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
  <img class="img NSFW vertical" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
  <img class="img Architectural" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
  <img class="img Sunsets Landscapes" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
  <img class="img Abstract" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
  <img class="img NSFW LondonAndrews" src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
</section>
```